# How do I do statisticly analyze groups with different numbers of individuals and nested treatmens?

Tags: r, biostatistics

I am currently working on my MSC thesis, but I fear I don't have the level of statistical knowledge to analyze this data.
In my experiment there are 3 plant species with 31,40 and 82 individuals. They each have their own weight and height, so I need to implement that as well. There are 6 treatments in total, each treatment contains an erosion level and a flow speed (which is how quickly the water will stream in the setup).
For each erosion level, I used 2 different flow speeds. So I assume that flow speed is nested/blocked into the erosion. For every treatment the angle of the stem of the plant is measured compared to standing verticaly. Every individual stem went trough each treatment in the exact same order.
Is there anyway I can incorporate into a statistical analysis, preferably in R. I tried to make a schematic overview of how my data looks.
[image]

You would be the savior of my MSC thesis :)

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

I already tried to put the treatments into a vector but since the control groups all have a different length it does not work.

Comment: Please give some more information (sample size? ...) this is very little to work on.  Maybe add some plots and data excepts. Then edit your post for typos ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you for replying, I tried to fix my mistakes and added a picture illustrating how my data looks. Hopefully this helps.                                      
 Have a nice day , Sam

Comment: Thanks for adding those details. This might be a pretty simple model, but I still have some questions. The "angle" annotations make it seem that values like -25, -12, 5, 18,... in the table are the outcome values, angles relative to vertical measured for each individual (plant?) under each condition: is that correct? Also, it seems that each individual was tested under each condition. Was the order in which the conditions were presented the same for all individuals? Please edit the question again to add that information, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @EdM Thank you for trying to help me, I have edited the question to include the information. Have a wonderfull day , Sam :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multiple categorical predictor of `erosion`, `flowspeed`, and `species`, this is similar to what's called "repeated measures analysis of variance." That's a linear model in which you account for the repeated measurements on the same individuals. The problem is that classic repeated measures analysis of variance assumes equal numbers of observations in each treatment/species group, which you don't have.

One way to deal with the different numbers of observations is a linear mixed model. You use `erosion`, `flowspeed`, and `species` as fixed-effect predictors, the `angle` as the outcome, and treat the individual plants as providing a random effect.

You set up 1 row of data for each observation, with annotations of `angle`, `erosion`, `flowspeed`, `species`, and an `ID` indicating the individual plant. It's best with only 6 combinations of `erosion` with `flowspeed` to code them as categorical predictors, not as numeric. Include `height` and `weight` also on each line if you want to include those variables in the analysis. Use a set of `ID` values from 1 to 153 instead of re-numbering from 1 within each species. Otherwise the software will think that the plants with `ID=1` are all the same individual, and a member of all 3 species!

With the [`lme4` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=lme4) in R, you could start with something like:

```
myModel <- lmer(angle ~ erosion*flowspeed*species + (1|ID), data = myData)
```

That allows for different associations with `angle` depending on the *combinations* of `erosion` and `flowspeed` and `species`. It takes the repeated measurements into account by estimating different intercepts (estimated `angle` at reference levels of `erosion` and `flowspeed` and `species`) for the 153 individuals (ID). You don't need to worry about terminology like "nested." The software will correctly interpret the distribution of `ID` values among the treatment/species combinations.

That will return a large number of fixed-effect regression coefficients: by my quick count, 2 for `erosion`, 1 for `flowspeed`, 2 for `species`, 2 for `erosion:flowspeed` interactions, 4 for `erosion:species` interactions, 2 for `flowspeed:species` interactions, and 4 for `erosion:flowspeed:species` interactions. Do NOT spend much time trying to figure those coefficients out individually. They describe the model in a way that subsequent analysis with other software will make clearer. You will also get an estimate of the variance among the `ID`-specific intercept values.

I'd recommend using the `Anova()` function in the R [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) to evaluate the overall associations of each of `erosion` and `flowspeed` and `species`, and their sets of interactions, with the `angle` outcome. The "Type II" default analysis provided by that function handles different numbers of observations properly, while the standard `anova()` or `aov()` functions in R don't.

You then can use post-modeling software like that in the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) to evaluate and compare predicted `angle` values among combinations of fixed-effect predictors.

You do have to check whether the assumptions of the linear model are reasonably well met. The main issue with categorical predictors is whether the ranges of residuals (differences between observed and predicted `angle` values) are similar over the range of predicted values. If that's not the case, you might have to consider some pre-transformation of the `angle` values. A reasonably normal distribution of the residuals is a plus, but not so critical when you have a large number of observations.

The above doesn't incorporate `height` and `weight` explicitly in the model. It includes them implicitly in the `ID` values and the corresponding random intercepts. You could add them as explicit predictors in the model. If you do, think carefully about the form in which to include them. If you just include them as linear terms, you are implicitly assuming that the `angle` is linearly and additively associated with each of `height` and `weight` on top of all of the other effects associated with `erosion` and `flowspeed` and `species`. Is that reasonable?

Finally, there is one limitation to the study design that you need to address in discussing your results. As all plants received the same treatments in the same order, you can't rule out the possibility of some time- or exposure-dependence of the results. That is, the results of later treatment combinations might not just depend on `erosion` and `flowspeed` and `species` but also on the time elapsed or treatments previously experienced.